# Displaying A Forms Submission Result Using AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms

I am designing a website in which all pages that the users selects from the menu are loaded into a specific div area of the page and was wondering how i create the functionality that when a user submits a form, instead of going to the browser then navigation to the form, having it load the results into the same div section.

My index page is like this:

```
<body>
    <?php
    echo "<div id=\"siteLogo\">";
        require("public/includes/templates/header.php");
    echo "</div>";
    "<div id=\"siteMenu\">";
        require("public/includes/templates/menu.php");
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div id=\"siteContent\">";
        require("public/includes/templates/home.php");
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div id=\"siteFooter\">";
        require("public/includes/templates/footer.php");
    echo "</div>";
?>
```

When the page is then rendered it takes this form, with their contents of course:

```
<body>
    <div id="siteLogo">
    </div>
    <div id="siteLogo">
    </div>
    <div id="siteLogo">
    </div>
    <div id="siteLogo">
    </div>
</body>
```

When the page is then rendered there are four divs areas each containing their respective contents. All items selected from the menu (menu.php) are then loaded into the web_Content div area using the following code (rendered HTML and the Javascript for AJAX loading)

```
<ul> 
    <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="help.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
-----------------------------------------------
$('#siteMenu a').click(function(e)
{
    $('#web_Content').load($(this).attr('href'), function()
    {
    })
});
```

Now when i add a form to my menu, it does as expected and loads the contents (form.php) into the #siteContents div area. I would now like to be able to make the website function so that when the form is submitted, the data is sent to a script (newDataPost.php for example) and have this script injected into the #siteContents div like the way in which the menu injects selected pages into that div?

I cant seem to figure out a way in which to do this, Could any of the more experienced web developers know a way in which to inject a script into a div on submission of a form?

Answer (score 0):

Look at changing the submit event on the form to do an ajax call that accepts a serialized form. Something like so:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.get('some_endpoint.php', {form_data :$(this).serialize() }, function (data) {
   // your callback to insert new html into the div
  })

});
```